# Latest version of XML not loaded in Firefox though works OK in IE

Tags: xml, firefox, actionscript-2

I am using AS2. I load an XML file in my movie. Somehow, the XML file is loaded. Now. if I change the XML file, the latest XML file do not appear in FireFox while lates XML file appears in IE.
Can anybody tell what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Clear your cache?

Answer (score 0):

Taking it further, you'll want to make sure that this situation doesn't arise in the future - i.e. after you've cleared your cache this time...

There are several methods:

1. Using a "cache-buster" string appended to the location of the file - e.g.

   ```
   ./data.xml?nocache=010920091407
   ```

   where you use the Date object to dynamically generate the value of nocache.  This is OK, but means that the XML will *never* be cached, since every time the flash is loaded the nocache value will change.
2. Dynamically generating the XML contents - i.e. calling

   ```
   ./data.php
   ```

   Same issue as the above: the content is never cached but loaded afresh *every* page view
3. **Better:** "Autoversioning"

   1. use PHP alter the path to the file such that

      ```
      ./data.xml
      ```

      becomes

      ```
      ./data.010920091407.xml
      ```

      where 010920091407 is the filemtime value of the file (i.e. when it was last updated)
   2. pass this value in to your flash app via flashvars when embedding it.
   3. Use a mod_rewrite rule (e.g. in a .htaccess file) to translate the path for files with this naming convention:

      ```
      RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(.+[0-9])\.(js|css|swf|xml)$ $1.$3
      ```

      strips out the

      ```
      .010920091407
      ```

      and returns the file at

      ```
      ./data.xml
      ```

      but the *browser* thinks it's loading a new file.
      Now you can guarantee that users will load a new version of the file every time it does change, but from cache if it hasn't.
      (You'll see that here I've told it to do this to any of the files I typically need to be guaranteed of an update: *.js, *.css and *.swf as well)

   (Obviously this is assuming a LAMP server, but the principle is the same under any stack)

Update: a useful tutorial can be found here:
http://particletree.com/notebook/automatically-version-your-css-and-javascript-files/
A more in-depth one is here:
http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/125